# Subquery select with outer value for inner where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Users can have multiple records in the subscriptions table.

What I want to do is return their first name, last name, email, start date (of their first subscription, select start_date from subscriptions order by start_date asc limit 1, but I need it for that specific user)

```
// users
id
first_name
last_name
email

// subscriptions
id
email
start_date (TIMESTAMP)
end_date (TIMESTAMP)
status
```

I thought this would work, but it does not seem to:

```
select 
    distinct(users.email), status, first_name, last_name,
    (select start_date from subscriptions where subscriptions.email = users.email order by start_date asc limit 1) as start_date 
from 
    subscriptions sub 
join 
    users u on sub.email = u.email
order by 
    sub.end_date desc
```

That returns the same start_date for everyone, since it's probably pulling the first one it matches.

SQL fiddle with the schema: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/245c05/5

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query. And note that DISTINCT is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query:

```
select s.*
from subscriptions s
where s.start_date = (select min(start_date) from subscriptions where email = s.email)
```

returns the row for each user's first subscription.
Join it to `users`:

```
select u.*, t.status, t.start_date
from users u 
left join (
  select s.*
  from subscriptions s
  where s.start_date = (select min(start_date) from subscriptions where email = s.email)  
) t on t.email = u.email
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8RQr8gBRXPj7QHH4YpPZi4/0).
Results:

```
| id  | email          | first_name | last_name | status   | start_date          |
| --- | -------------- | ---------- | --------- | -------- | ------------------- |
| 1   | john@aol.com   | John       | Smith     | active   | 2018-02-12 23:34:02 |
| 2   | jim@aol.com    | Jim        | Smith     | canceled | 2016-03-02 23:34:02 |
| 3   | jerry@aol.com  | Jerry      | Smith     | active   | 2017-12-12 23:34:02 |
| 4   | jackie@aol.com | Jackie     | Smith     | active   | 2018-05-22 23:34:02 |
```